# VBA Excel detect always hidden rows and columns in With x End With loop?

Tags: excel, vba

How to detect always in `With xx end With`also hidden columns and rows? My code's current variables values are changing depending on that are the columns and rows hidden or not. That prevents my code working on properly.

```
With myMatrixSheet
            lastRow = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
            lastColumn = .Cells(7,.UsedRange.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).column + 1
End With
```

My solved and final code look likes below

```
With myMatrixSheet

If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Cells) <> 0 Then
    lastRow = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                  After:=.Range("A1"), _
                  Lookat:=xlPart, _
                  LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                  SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                  SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                  MatchCase:=False).row
Else
    lastRow = 1
End If

If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Cells) <> 0 Then
    lastColumn = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                  After:=.Range("A1"), _
                  Lookat:=xlPart, _
                  LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                  SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                  SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                  MatchCase:=False).column
Else
    lastColumn = 1
End If
End With
```

Answer (score 2):

I find `FIND` the easiest way (other methods are available):

```
Sub Test()

    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim LastColumn As Long

    With Sheet1
        LastRow = .Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
        LastColumn = .Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column
    End With

    If LastRow = 0 Then LastRow = 1
    If LastColumn = 0 Then LastColumn = 1

    '--OR USE SEPARATE FUNCTION--

    Dim rLastCell As Range
    Set rLastCell = LastCell(Sheet1)
    Debug.Print rLastCell.Row & " : " & rLastCell.Column

End Sub

Public Function LastCell(wrkSht As Worksheet) As Range

    Dim lLastCol As Long, lLastRow As Long

    On Error Resume Next

    With wrkSht
            lLastCol = .Cells.Find("*", , , , xlByColumns, xlPrevious).Column
            lLastRow = .Cells.Find("*", , , , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row

        If lLastCol = 0 Then lLastCol = 1
        If lLastRow = 0 Then lLastRow = 1

        Set LastCell = .Cells(lLastRow, lLastCol)
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0

End Function
```

The `FIND` solution will be covered in the link provided by @Vityata.

Answer (score 1):

To get the last of the rows/columns also when they are hidden:

`Activesheet.cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row`
`Activesheet.cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column`

If you need the specific column, use it like this:

```
Public Function GetLastRow(lngCol As Long) As Long   

    GetLastRow = ActiveSheet.Columns(3).Find(What:="*", SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row  

End Function
```

In general, this is probably the best article for last rows and columns:
https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s9/win005.htm

Comment: Hi, yours example calculates all possible rows in the sheet. I just want last row where is text.

Comment: @AratioD Change the `Cells` part to your used range... like `Columns(3)`